# i am trying to implement tree data structure in c language. but the code is automatically stop. inorder traversal of the tree is not printed

Tags: c, data-structures

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

// here i have created structure

struct node
{
    struct node *left;
    int data;
    struct node *right;
};

// here the root node is created

struct node *root=NULL;

// it is a create function which create the tree and take input from the user

struct node *createTree(){
    root=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    printf("Enter Data : \n");
    int data;
    scanf("%d",&data);

    if(data==-1) return NULL;

    root->data = data;

    printf("Enter data for left node of %d : \n",data);
    root->left=createTree();

    printf("Enter data for right node of %d : \n",data);
    root->right=createTree();
    
    // the root node is returned from this function
    return root;
}

// here i am trying to print the root in inorder traversal but it is not printing

void inorderT(struct node *root){
    if (root == NULL) return;
    inorderT(root->left);
    printf("%d \n",root->data);
    inorderT(root->right);
}

void main(){
    createTree();
    inorderT(root);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that every time you call `createTree()`, you modify the very same node `root`. Therefore, all of the nodes are simply pointers to `root`, which is `NULL`, because the last node you create must be `NULL`.

Modify your `createTree()` function in the following way:

```
struct node *createTree() {
    struct node *r = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    printf("Enter Data: \n");
    scanf("%d", &r->data);

    if (r->data == -1) {
        free(r);
        return NULL;
    }

    printf("Enter data for left node of %d : \n",r->data);
    r->left=createTree();

    printf("Enter data for right node of %d : \n",r->data);
    r->right=createTree();

    return r;
}
```

And then your `main()`:

```
void main(){
    root = createTree();
    inorderT(root);
}
```

Also, you should remember to `free()` all memory before terminating the program.

Comment: ...and move `struct node *root=NULL;` away from global and into `main().` So `struct node *root = createTree();`